# Binding a textfield to an imageview in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently trying to bind a textfield to an imageview, depending on what I type, such and such picture should appear on the imageview. The pictures are in the same package as the .fxml file.I have already figured out that I have to do it with ObjectBinding, but I really can't figure out the rest. I don't know how to use the compute value method, and I don't know as what I should return the image name. Here is the code I have already written:

*ImageViewBinding.java*

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ImageViewBinding extends ObjectBinding {

    private StringProperty imageName;    

    public ImageViewBinding(StringProperty imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;       
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Object computeValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public StringProperty calculate() {    
        return imageName;
    }
}
```

*ImageViewController.java*

```
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import model.ImageViewBinding;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ImageViewController implements Initializable {    

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtField;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {    
        ImageViewBinding imageViewBinding = new ImageViewBinding(
            txtField.textProperty()
        );

        imageView.imageProperty().bind(imageViewBinding);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help and any critique given.

Answer (score 2):

In order to bind the `imageProperty` to your binding, you need the binding to be an `ObjectBinding<Image>`. The `computeValue(...)` method should compute the image from the string value, and return it.

Since the images are in the same folder as the FXML file, you probably want to pass the location of the FXML to the binding in order to resolve that location.

You should also deal appropriately with images that don't exist; here I just return null in that case.

```
public class ImageViewBinding extends ObjectBinding<Image> {

    private StringProperty imageName;
    private URL location ;

    public ImageViewBinding(StringProperty imageName, URL location) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.location = location ;
        bind(imageName);
    }


    @Override
    protected Image computeValue() {
        try {
            return new Image(location.toURI().resolve(imageName.get()).toString());
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    ImageViewBinding imageViewBinding = new ImageViewBinding(txtField.textProperty(), location);

    imageView.imageProperty().bind(imageViewBinding);
}
```

Note that, since the images in the same package as the FXML file are necessarily a set of fixed possible values, it's almost certainly a better user experience here to use a `ComboBox` instead of a `TextField`.